# Low disk space warning but df reports only 56% used

Tags: linux, centos

I am getting low disk space warnings but when I check the disk space, only 56% is used. I am thinking of giving the system a reboot as it's reported incorrect disk usage in the past.

[image]

Here's the output of df -h

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_q12pmds-lv_root
                   20G  7.5G   12G  41% /
tmpfs                 7.5G   20K  7.5G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2             477M   78M  374M  18% /boot
/dev/sda1             128M  256K  128M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/vg_q12pmds-lv_home
                   50G   26G   21G  56% /home
/dev/mapper/vg_q12pmds-LogVol03
                   99G   52G   42G  56% /home2
/dev/mapper/vg_q12pmds-lv_log
                  4.8G  710M  3.9G  16% /var/log
/dev/sdb1             3.6T  145G  3.3T   5% /media/d1c651ff-b7c3-4b9e-a573-ada44b942b0c
```

Here's the output of df -i

```
Filesystem              Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_q12pmds-lv_root
                   1310720 185599   1125121   15% /
tmpfs                  1964594      6   1964588    1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2               128016     29    127987    1% /boot
/dev/sda1                    0      0         0     - /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/vg_q12pmds-lv_home
                   3276800  12271   3264529    1% /home
/dev/mapper/vg_q12pmds-LogVol03
                   6553600     39   6553561    1% /home2
/dev/mapper/vg_q12pmds-lv_log
                    327680    348    327332    1% /var/log
/dev/sdb1            244195328     13 244195315    1% /media/d1c651ff-b7c3-4b9e-a573-ada44b942b0c
```

Comment: Try this out - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82618/df-command-not-showing-correct-values

Comment: What is the result of `df -i`? And post text, not images (when applicable)

Comment: I tried lsof -a +L /dev/mapper/vg_q12pmds-LogVol03 and there is no output